# Using subprocess to start several game servers

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to make an application that start several game servers based on data from a database, then restarts them if they crash and stops them when the application is exiting.

I'm wondering if my example code is good or if I should use another approach.

Any downsides with this?

**My code so far:**

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import time

# replace following with a database
servers = [
    {
        "name": "Server #1",
        "path": "/home/myuser/server1/",
        "executable": "srcds_linux",
        "options": "-switches -n -stuff"
    },
    {
        "name": "Server #2",
        "path": "/home/myuser/server2/",
        "executable": "srcds_linux",
        "options": "-some -other -switches"
    }
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = []

    for server in servers:
        print "Starting server '%s'" % server["name"]

        process = subprocess.Popen(
            shlex.split("./%s %s" % (server["executable"], server["options"])),
            cwd=server["path"]

            # stdin=...
            # stdout=...
        )

        processes.append(process)

    while True:
        # check if all processes are running, else restart them..

        time.sleep(1)
```

What other ways are there to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Which one is the best and why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use `multiprocessing` to manage your process pool, and have the `target` function call one of the `os.exec*` variants to start the actual server executable. You can then poll `is_alive()` of the sub processes to respawn anything that died.